# Lebesgue Integrable inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $f, g$ and $h$ are measurable and that $f\leq g\leq h$ a.e. If $f$ and $h$ are Lebesgue integrable , does it follow that $g$ is Lebesgue integrable? Explain.

Any idea how I start this problem? Is there a counter example this will not be true?

Comment: A general (not necessarily positive) function $\phi$ is Lebesgue integrable if the area between the graph of $\phi$ and the x-axis is finite. In your case: $g$ must be integrable too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inequalities imply that a.e. $$|g|\le \max (|f|,|h|)\le |f|+|h|.$$

$f$ and $h$ are integrable, hence so are $|f|$ and $|h|$ (by definition). The sum of two integrable functions is also integrable. So, $|g|$ is measurable, non-negative and bounded by integrable function, hence integrable. By definition, $g$ is integrable.

**edit**

why $a\le b\le c$ implies $|b|\le \max(|a|,|c|)$?

The most staightforward way is to consider two possible cases:

1. $ b \le 0$, hence $|b|=-b \le -a=|a|\le \max(|a|,|c|)$
2. $b\ge 0$, hence $0\le |b|=b\le c=|c|\le \max(|a|,|c|)$.

Comment: I agree with your answer but, can you expand on the first part of the inequality. I see the second part is true, but I just don't see the first part yet. Thanks

Comment: @Lucas see edits.

Comment: thanks, i got it